# Test Connection to WebLogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a `javax.naming.Context`and the `t3://servername:port` URL of a WebLogic server. When interacting with the server, if the connection fails, the method calls will hang.

Is there a way to test if a connection can be made to the WebLogic server?

I have tried `InetAddress` and `URL`, but neither of them recognize the protocol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use **weblogic.Admin** utility to test the connection to the weblogic server

eg. Ping

java weblogic.Admin -url t3://host:port -username *yourUserName* -password *yourPassword* PING *timeOut*

Reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/cli.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Thin T3 Client, found in the wlthint3client.jar, to make t3 protocol connections to WebLogic.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13717/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT379